Regression - Model looks good overall but R2 unexpectedly negatively high
I have been building a linear regression model with around 150 rows of data. I checked the correlation of the parameters with the target variable and tried to keep only them as I have less data and wanted to have a simple linear model.
The MAE and MAPE are really decent enough:
Train MAPE: 3.3%, Val MAPE: 4.9%
The train data and validation data graph also looks decent enough, the blue line represents actual values for training data and orange line represents predicted values on train data. The green line represents actual values for validation data and red line represents predicted values:

However, my:
Train R2: 0.63, Val R2: -0.37
I have searched across many resources, asked Google Gemini ChatGPT, got similar responses but I am still not able to figure out why my R2 is coming out to be so weird when everything else seems to be decent. Can we use this model to implement or infer in real-world?
Please note: I have also tried Random Forest, LightGBM, XGBoost and many other linear and bagging/boosting models, results are almost similar. Graph looks ok, MAE, MAPE looks good but R2 is not in normal range.

How many variables do you have ? As a starting point, could you show us a simple linear model with the same variables/features as the model that produced that plot, using ‘lm’ if using R, or ‘OLS’ if using Python/statsmodels. Just edit the question and add the summary output of the model.

I have around 160 rows and 15-20 feature columns shortlisted from 40-45 columns using RFECV

The MAE and MAPE are really decent enough How do you assess that to be true?

I am getting a MAPE of 0.02 on training data and 0.04 on validation data. MAE is 25 on train and 45 on validation. Also, going by the definition of R2, don't you think the graph is not justified for such a high negative R2

But how do you assess those to be good values?

2% error rate on train, 4% on validation, considering my range of target variable, it is 800-1200, so, 25-45 is a good MAE I would say as well as the graph

my point is if the R2 is so highly negative then the graph, the MAPE and the MAE really doesn't make sense. I am unable to understand what's the issue in this case

I find graphs like yours to be problematic. At least my eyes look at Euclidean distance between the curves. However, what we care about is vertical distance. If you graph a scatterplot of the true and predicted values, how does it look? You seem to have a number of bad misses. $//$ Depending on the particular calculation, $R^2<0$ is totally reasonable, despite being a "squared" quantity. Sure, $R^2<0$ is undesirable, but it makes sense and is informative in that is flags the predictions as being worse than that of a benchmark model that always predicts $\bar y$.

See this recent answer on the application of OLS to time series data, which it appears to be what you are working with. What you are seeing may be an artifact of autocorrelation.
